# What is Core Data Source Fetch

Tags: xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I am looking at the **Entity Mapping** panel of core data in Xcode, and notice a setting named **Source Fetch**. There are two options **Default** and **Custom**. What is this **Source Fetch** about?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You specify the sourceExpression for the mapping using a combination of the the source fetch popup menu and the text view beneath it. You can select either the default fetch—in which case you can optionally specify a filter predicate for the fetch—or a custom fetch, in which case you specify the source expression directly.

[Entity Mapping Detail](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeMappingTool/Articles/xmmModelPane.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006865-SW5)